# OpenGL glsl: can't pass data from program to shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am writing a program that sends data from a function in a C++ program to a vertex shader. A program ID is passed into the function as follows:

```
void setUpOrtho(GLuint program) {
    glUseProgram( program );
    GLint myUniformLocation = glGetUniformLocation( program, "sx" );
    glUniform1f( myUniformLocation, 2.0 );
}
```

The data being passed to the shader is supposed to be an argument The glsl code is as follows:

```
attribute vec4 vPosition;
uniform float sx;

void main() {
    mat4 M = mat4( sx, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0 );
    gl_Position = M*vPosition;
```

}

And nothing gets rendered. But if I replace sx with 2.0, it displays just fine. Why isn't the 2.0 being successfully passed from the cpp to the glsl?

Comment: 2.0 is a double not a float. Try 2.0f instead. I don't know if this could be the problem.

Comment: @Heisenbug Didn't work. Good catch, though.

Comment: Double check that `program` is valid and `myUniformLocation` is set to valid location.

Comment: Is glUniform1f spelled correctly in your source code? It is spelled incorrectly in your code example.

Comment: @bwroga Yea, it's spelled correctly in the code. Sorry about that, I didn't copy and paste this. Also worth noting is that my code does compile.

Comment: @Maf `glUseProgram` is called on `program` before passing it into `setUpOrtho`. How would I check that `myUniformLocation` is set to a valid location?

Comment: If myUniformLocation is not -1 then it should be valid.

Comment: @bwroga: Thank you. I found the problem, though it's not a problem so much as it was me not knowing the full functionality of the code I was given. It turned out that setUpOrtho wasn't even being called, and I had to hit a key on the keyboard to have it called (it gives an option between orthographic and frustum viewing). When I hit the key it displayed just fine.

Comment: @ZettaSuro: This is exactly the reason why in the programs I develop **every** function on entry calls a logging function, including the values of the passed parameters. In super verbose mode the logging system even creates backtraces. This makes spotting errors like this rather easy.

Comment: @datenwolf I'll definitely need to look into that. I really need to get better at debugging.